# `node : not found` when trying to `npm run dev`

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, svelte

I'm trying to run a [Svelte example project](https://svelte.dev/blog/the-easiest-way-to-get-started) on my Windows 10 system. I'm using Node v14.17.0 and npm v6.14.13. When I run `npm run dev` at the project level directory, I get the following error.

```
C:\...\my-svelte-project>npm run dev

> svelte-app@1.0.0 dev C:\...\my-svelte-project
> rollup -c -w

/mnt/c/.../my-svelte-project/node_modules/.bin/rollup: 12: /mnt/c/.../my-svelte-project/node_modules/.bin/rollup: node: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file bash
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! svelte-app@1.0.0 dev: `rollup -c -w`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the svelte-app@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-22T12_25_15_891Z-debug.log
```

I can't seem to figure out the error, and I've tried a range of suggestions available online. Has anyone come across this? I'm most confused with the `node : not found prompt` even though node is clearly installed and on the Path variable.

Additional info:
I tried to run `rollup -c -w`, and this is the error log I get -

```
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error syscall spawn bash
23 error file bash
24 error path bash
25 error errno -4058
26 error svelte-app@1.0.0 start: `sirv public --no-clear`
26 error spawn bash ENOENT
27 error Failed at the svelte-app@1.0.0 start script.
27 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
28 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

Comment: Can you try `npm cache clean --force` and then deleting `node_modules` folder and doing `npm install` again

Comment: That seems to be the most popular suggestion online, and I've tried that, but to no effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have tried reinstalling node modules and/or node overall:

The error seems to be with a lack of access to/from `bash` to the `sirv` command - which we can deduce from ENOENT (short for Error NO Entry). If you look at [npm settings docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-start#script-shell) we can see how to configure which shell npm tries to use in running its scripts. I suspect if you ran `npm config get script-shell` you would get `bash` - which in the case of windows is referring to git bash specifically.

On my system with a working svelte example I have this set to `null` (which I did not set manually and weirdly isn't one of the options in the docs) so you can try to set it with `npm config set script-shell=null` or if that doesn't save your bacon try `npm config set script-shell=cmd.exe`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been working on this bug for way too long, this fixed it!